# Python - Parsing string to timedelta when hours value is greater than 24

Tags: python, datetime

I am running a daily report and I'd like to keep a log of how long it takes to run each day.
I get a report_time timedelta object by calling datetime.datetime.now() at beginning and end and then getting the difference between the two values.

I have a text file that has two lines. Line 1 is today's run-time. Line 2 is total cumulative run time.

The issue is that when I try to parse Line 2 into a datetime.datetime object (to then create a timedelta object to add today's report time) it won't let me do so if the cumulative run time is over 24 hours (I guess because it no longer makes a valid date.

Any idea how to get around this (essentially parse a string into a time.delta object when it won't conform to a datetime.datetime format?

Code:

```
report_stats = f.read()
today_cumulative_reports_time = report_stats.splitlines()[0]
prev_total_reports_time = report_stats.splitlines()[1]
today_cumulative_reports_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(today_cumulative_reports_time, 
'%H:%M:%S.%f')

today_cumulative_reports_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=today_cumulative_reports_time.hour, 
minutes=today_cumulative_reports_time.minute,
                    seconds=today_cumulative_reports_time.second, 
microseconds=today_cumulative_reports_time.microsecond)
prev_total_reports_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(prev_total_reports_time, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
prev_total_reports_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=prev_total_reports_time.hour, 
minutes=prev_total_reports_time.minute,
               seconds=prev_total_reports_time.second, 
microseconds=prev_total_reports_time.microsecond)
cumulative_run_time = report_time + today_cumulative_reports_time + prev_total_reports_time
f.close()

Error:

ValueError: time data '24:54:03.294820' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually parse the string and then construct the `timedelta` object:

```
from datetime import timedelta

time_string = '24:54:03.294820'
hours, minutes, seconds = map(float, time_string.split(':'))
t_delta = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
print(t_delta)
```

outputs

```
1 day, 0:54:03.294820
```